# Redirecting to a part of a page, specifically top of the page

Tags: html, iframe

I have this page and i am using an Iframe.

I do my actions in my iframe and it automatically resize, but when the iframe is long (vertically), 
and i click on a button that would redirect the page to the next, my parent page is still in the bottom part, and the iframe pgae is at the top.

how would i redirect the parent page to scroll up once location:PAGE.php is triggered, location:PAGE.php is the one inside the iframe.

I hope i asked it properly. i tried a url using #IDofDIV but it only redirects inside of the iframe, i need to redirect outside of the frame. so it goes on top again.

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add onload="parent.scrollTo(0,0);" on your PAGE.php.

Comment: Using a link on a name (ex document.top.location.href='#top';) also works.